# Enlarge frame for same page link/code

Tags: xcode

Is there any way i can enlarge this code so the frame shows bigger then it is rather then me having to scroll up and down to see it, as in width and height. its a show the link in same page code.

code:

```
<a href='link1.html' target='myIframe'>link1</a><br /> <iframe name='myIframe'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

Code:

```
<a href='link1.html' target='myIframe'>link1</a><br /> <iframe name='myIframe' width="500" height="400"></iframe>
```